# Reduce gap between plot area and actual chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to reduce the gap between plot area and actual chart in gauge chart,
i have used

> HighchartsOptionFactory highchartsFactory = new 
>   JsoHighchartsOptionFactory();
>           ChartOptions options = highchartsFactory.createChartOptions();
>           options.chart().type("solidgauge");
>            options.chart().marginTop(0).marginLeft(0).marginBottom(0).marginRight(0);
>           options.chart().spacingLeft(0).spacingTop(0).spacingRight(0).spacingBottom(0);

but still there is so much of waste space between plot area and actual chart.
Can somebody help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to also set up a pane size and its outer radius.

The example in js, but the wrapper API should be the same.

```
pane: {
      size: '100%',
      background: {
        outerRadius: '100%'
      }
    },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ct3pm5op/1/